# length erros in gstat using cross validation krigecv in R

Tags: r, gstat

Today  I am having a problem which I could not find a solution to. I want to use krigcv cross validation using gstat in R and i have an error message:

0%Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula), as(data, "data.frame"), na.action = na.fail) : variable lengths differ (found for 'x')

this is my code line:
QCini.uk.cv <- krige.cv(QCini$var1 ~ x + y + I(y^2) + I(y^3) + I(x * y^2) + x:y, QCini, Vresfit.fi.vgm)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the data.frame in the formula argument, and try

```
QCini.uk.cv <- krige.cv(var1 ~ x + y + I(y^2) + I(y^3) + I(x * y^2) + 
  x:y, QCini, Vresfit.fi.vgm)
```